# Multiple channel's message comes into single channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

i am fresher of Spring Integration, i am confuing one question which i have multiple channels but now i want to assemble messages from those channel into single channel, how to implement it ? my senario is that i have lots of businees modues and each module will corresponding to one channel, those channels will receive the request then assemble the message into one single channel , then output to the jms server:

is below code possible ?

```
<channel id='a'/> <bridge input-channel='a' out-channel='assembled'/>
<channel id='b'/> <bridge input-channel='b' out-channel='assembled'/>
<channel id='b'/> <bridge input-channel='c' out-channel='assembled'/>
<channel id='c'/> <bridge input-channel='d' out-channel='assembled'/>

<channel id='assembled'/>

<!-- the router will desicde which jms gateway to be sent  -->
<router input-channel='assembled' > 

<channel id='to_jms1'/>
<channel id='to_jms2'/>

<jms-outbound-gateway id='jms1' channel='to_jms1'/>
<jms-outbound-gateway id='jms2' channel='to_jms2'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to send each individual message arriving on a, b, c etc to the same channel, then what you have above will work.

If you want to merge together the messages on a, b, c, d into a single message then after the bridges, use an `<aggregator/>` with appropriate correlation and release strategies.

See the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) for more information.

Comment: hi Gary Russell, not merge into single one message, i just want then comes into single channel... i need to 'router' the messages, but tag ROUTER will only accept one input channel .So i need to assemble multiple message of channels into single channel then router them...

Comment: In that case, you are correct - just bridge them to a single channel (or set the output channel of each flow to `assembled`).

Comment: Hello. Would the fact of merging all messages into a single channel produce a bottleneck on that channel? Or it does not have nothing to do? For example, for a logging system, having a single channel for logging the information and then split the messages to multiple channels, would it be a good aproach?

Comment: There is no "bottleneck"; with a direct channel the subscribing endpoint(s) run on the calling threads, which have no interaction with each other - but your downstream components might be a bottleneck - but changing the channel types (or using a different channel for each) won't help that - unless you need a separate instance of those components for each producer. So, no, using a single `DirectChannel` does not create a bottleneck.

Comment: How could you achieve this without the use of XML, i.e. only Java Config? Since the channel names comes from the bean name and spring will ignore/override 2 beans with same name?

Comment: I don't understand the question "channel names comes from the bean name" - it's better to ask a new question and reference this one (and provide more details); the admins here don't like extended comments on answers.