# Multiple channels sent to single channel with spring-integration annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-integration

How can I have 2 channels output to a single channel with spring integration without using XML. Similar to the following question [Multiple channel's message comes into single channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555008/multiple-channels-message-comes-into-single-channel)

I have 2 PollableChannel beans in my context that I wish to route messages from both (non aggregated) to a single @ServiceActivator, i.e. accomplishing something like the following:

```
@Bean("Channel1") PollableChannel c1() {...}
@Bean("Channel2") PollableChannel c2() {...}

?? How to interleave/combine Channel1 and Channel2 into a single channel

...
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "Channel1and2")
void handle(msg: MyMessage) {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Bean("Channel1") 
@BridgeTo("Channel1and2")
PollableChannel c1() {...}

@Bean("Channel2") 
@BridgeTo("Channel1and2")
PollableChannel c2() {...}
```

Pay attention to te `@BridgeTo` annotation. From its JavaDocs:

```
* Messaging Annotation to mark a {@link org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean}
* method for a {@link org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel} to produce a
* {@link org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler} and Consumer Endpoint.
* <p>
* The {@link org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel} {@link org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean}
* marked with this annotation is used as the {@code inputChannel} for the
* {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint}
* and determines the type of endpoint -
* {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer} or
* {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer}.
```

You can also consider to use the `@Poller` on that `@BridgeTo`, since your input channels are `PollableChannel`.

The Reference Manual on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#_creating_a_bridge_with_annotations